# Why is my Go Proxy Server sticking to a single child server when sending requests to certain websites?

Tags: go, ubuntu, proxy, network-programming, ipv6

I have built a proxy server with this GitHub project (https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy), and this server is accepting requests from the nodejs puppeteer.

The proxy server is listening on the IPv6 address and sends requests further to the child proxy server and from there, traffic is going to desired website.
I have 6 child servers with 1000 ip defined in a Netplan configuration (each server has full /64), so total of 6000k URLs. On each child server with 1000 URLs, go is running 1000 servers with the "sync" package.

Now about the functionality, after I start the main process in main.go, inside go collect all those URLs and store them ServerPool struct, struct code is like this:

```
type ServerPool struct {
    mu            sync.Mutex
    servers       []*url.URL
    lockedWorkers []string
}
```

Next, I have defined also method getNextServer() method which is digging from a list of URLs and returning one IP to the next operation. From there, with the help of the "github goproxy" package, there is an inside method OnRequest(), and with that method, you can manipulate connect behavior.

Code example:

```
proxy.OnRequest().DoFunc(func(req *http.Request, ctx *goproxy.ProxyCtx) (*http.Request, *http.Response) {

    serverUrl, err := serverPool.GetNextServer()
    proxy.Tr.Proxy = func(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
       return url.Parse(serverUrl.String())
    }
    proxy.ConnectDial = proxy.NewConnectDialToProxyWithHandler(serverUrl.String(), nil)

    return req, nil
})
```

Now this method OnRequest() dials the child proxy and the child proxy server is doing the end operation. That's all fine and working!

What is the issue?
The issue is that on some special websites, it won't execute OnRequest() method, won't log/print anything, and won't pick the next server.

But, what does he want now to do with these specific websites? The proxy server (in the main.go) somehow picks one of the child servers and like glue stick to him and won't switch to another child server. But yes, sometimes after a few golang servers start/stop it wants to go to the next server and send the traffic, but again in the first connect, again it sticks to that new one and won't change to another till I again do a few start/stop.

This is so strange to me, and not sure in which way to go and how to overcome this.
Did somebody have the same issue, or there is there maybe something to configure? Also maybe to share more info, whatever.
Help, please!

I tried clearing caching, changing IPs, changing servers, rebooting, etc, still the same.

Comment: This is not relevant to your issue, but you will run into data race if there are multiple requests arrive at the same time and all want to modify `proxy`.

Comment: @ZekeLu thanks for answering. 
It does not matter, I tested with one request per time, and it's the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to drop this. Did things all over again with pure go packages, not custom.